# Optional parameters on request class

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs

What is the proper way to handle optional parameters on a service request?

Lets say in this scenario i want to have also `$title` as optional parameter

```
<?php
namespace Lw\Application\Service\Wish;
class AddWishRequest
{
    private $userId;
    private $email;
    private $content;

    public function __construct($userId, $email, $content)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function userId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function email()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

Example from [here](https://github.com/dddinphp/last-wishes/blob/master/src/Lw/Application/Service/Wish/AddWishRequest.php)

Comment: Please consider the answer who helped you to mark as correct.

Comment: Sure, i need to put a bit of more time on this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in DDD and following the rules of clean code also,  if you have optional parameters,  you have multiple constructors, two in this case:

- One for just the mandatory arguments.
- One for all the arguments including the optional but in this constructor it would be mandatory too.

If you wanna construct the object without the optional argument you call the first one. And if you wanna supply a non null optional argument you use the second one.

Usually you should use factory methods with meaningful names, and hide the constructors.

AddWishRequest.create ( userId, email,  content)

AddWishRequest.createWithTitle ( userId, email,  content, title )

Comment: But what if i have 5 optional parameters, should i made all the combinations?

Comment: Usually in such a situation you would have just one constructor with the mandatory properties, and a setter with a meaningful name for each optional property, to set the values of the properties you want after create the object. In a setter the argument would be mandatory.

Comment: Yes i think about that solution but also i read that the setters should be avoided

Comment: I said setters to understand each other. I said with meaningful names,  i.e , don't name the method setProperty, give it a name with a meaning , like any other operation on the object.  A setter is just like any other operation,  it's an operation that changes the value of a property.  What should be avoided is to name the method setProperty,  not the method itself.

Comment: So i can use `addTitle(string $title){ $this->title = $title}`. Sorry for this simple details, im a bit overwhelmed with this concepts, there are a bit abstract for my now...

Comment: I mean what you should avoid is the systematic use of setters, but if your class has a real operation which consists on setting the value of a property, do it, but with a meningful name. Apart from that, according to clean code, you should avoid having more than 2 or 3 arguments, so you wouldn't have the problem of too many optional args. If you had more, it's because you can wrap some in just one object. I don't know your domain but it seems userId and email are of user, and title and content of a wish. So I would have 2 args instead of 4: userDto (id, email) and wishDto (title, content).

Comment: I was wondering if your example was "last wishes" from Carlos Buenosvinos and indeed it is. I've visited the link and saw it. Well it seems that the object is a "command", a dto to execute the "addWish" application service, and it is inmutable, no setters. You construct the request and then you cannot modify it. So I wouldn't have setters in the object request. I would go for the UserDto and WishDto objects as arguments of the request, so that you have less than 4 arguments. And anyway the checking to see if arguments are null is done in the service, not in the request

Comment: Thanks for your responses, i using this "last wishes" as a reference to learn this DDD stuff but the origin of the question is because i have other scenario where for example a user, apart of the mandatory email, password, have like 10 extra fields which should be in the user table. Any of this 10 extra fields are optional. Just for clarify, if use a DTO, should have a setField1(), setField2() and so on, and then send the DTO `UserDtoOptions` for example, as an extra and optional parameter of the request. And then the validation always in the service not in the DTO or the Request right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use optional arguments in any function call, also the constructor. Best practice is, to preceed "get" to the getters.

```
public function __construct($userId, $email, $content, $title = "")
```

means, $title is an optional argument. When not supplied, it is set to an empty string. You also could provide any other type or value.

```
namespace Lw\Application\Service\Wish;
class AddWishRequest
{
    private $userId;
    private $email;
    private $content;
    private $title;

    public function __construct($userId, $email, $content, $title = "")
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->content = $content;
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

}
```

**Update**

If you just declare a property like

```
private $property
```

then accessing it via `$this->property` with always be null (until you set a value). You should make the getter responsible for returning the correct values.

Following example will always return an array making use of the NULL-coalesce operator:

- if $something is true (or has an array content) will return $something
- else will return empty array

```
public function getSomething() : array {
  return $this->something ?? [];
}
```

Comment: What i have 5 parameters, i should leave empty or null some of them?

Comment: The constructor should receive as few as possible arguments.